# Why am I constantly running out of entropy?

Tags: linux, debian, random-number-generator

So I've been trying to create a new GPG key, and keep getting this well-known error:

```
Not enough random bytes available.  Please do some other work to give
the OS a chance to collect more entropy! (Need 294 more bytes)
```

So after 20 minutes of mouse movements that didn't even result in the encouraging `+++++`s at the bottom of the terminal, I tried what appears to have solved the problem for others: I installed `rng-tools` and ran:

```
rngd -r /dev/random
```

But that did nothing, either. No change at all. When I run:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

I never get an output above 60 or so.

So quite apart from the immediate issue -- i.e., not being able to generate a new GPG key -- **why would my machine be eating through entropy so quickly?** It seems as though there must be an underlying problem that ought to be addressed.

Comment: Some other process reading `/dev/random`? Check if `lsof /dev/random` shows something.

Comment: As for your workaround, *"rngd -r /dev/random [...] did nothing"*: it seems that it outputs to `/dev/random` by default, but in that command you're also *reading* from `/dev/random`. Are you sure that's the way to use it? Should't you read from some other source (or leave `-r` out of the command to use its defaults)? What if you run it in the foreground, `rngd -rf /dev/random`? (Also, [How to fix the entropy pool issue with RHEL 5.x](http://serverfault.com/questions/303935/how-to-fix-the-entropy-pool-issue-with-rhel-5-x) on Server Fault suggests to add a `-t 0.1` or `-t 0.001` parameter.)

Comment: Try installing haveged to gather additional entropy.

Comment: Are you sure your `rngd` command is right? (See my previous comment.)

Answer (score 1):

To get a bit more entropy check my answer on Server Fault for [Generate entropy for PGP key](https://serverfault.com/a/713041/67419).

Summary of that answer is:

- generate network and disk IOs;
- use haveged (but be careful when in a VM environment, see link).

As for your usage of rngd it won't "work". The program rngd is a sort of collector of random things which will after some de-biasing and whitening be used to feed a pool of entropy which will be used to generate random number using a PRNG. So rngd is one collector to provide "inputs" for the PRNG of Linux. When you use `/dev/random`, Linux estimates the entropy pool and if it decides it is good enough it will use it to generate a new random number for `/dev/random`. Check this [technical article on random numbers on LWN, see chapter "Administrator recommendations"](https://lwn.net/Articles/525459/).

Basically when calling `/dev/random` or gpg, you are using (and "depleting") the same entropy pool. So it won't help/work. Use a hardware RNG as source for rngd or any source like webcam, microphone, etc. but you will need appropriate drivers to link those to rngd. And this depends if you're using a VM and which distro you use.

*Note: if you're running bare metal (so not within a guest VM) you could use TPM for a hardware RNG. TPM could be not recommended if your worst enemy is the NSA ;-) read online about TPM. But if you want to use it, here is a way to link TPM to rngd (disclaimer I wrote this article) : http://www.berthon.eu/2015/using-tpm-as-a-source-of-randomness-entropy/*

And check this PDF presentation for information where entropy is being used :-) https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Potter-Understanding-And-Managing-Entropy-Usage.pdf

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Does this proposed answer solve your problem? Do you have further comments?

Comment: As an aside: the above comment will not alert the question asker; see http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-reply (But don't hold your breath; the OP has not responded to my earlier comments either.)